# CSS Position absolute/overflow:scroll issue

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="page" id="first">
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>

        <div class="nav bottom"><a href="#second">Second</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="second">
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="third">
    </div>
</div>
```

and following CSS code:

```
html, body { height:100% }
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.page {
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.nav {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
.nav.top {
    top:0;
}
.nav.bottom {
    bottom:0;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:160px;
}
```

As you may see, wrapper is the element that "simulates" browser window, basically the idea is to create "scrollable" pages of the website.

Everything works perfectly, but I'm facing one problem. If `div.page` has more content, scroll bar appear as expected, but the `.nav` `div` is positioned at the bottom of the browser window, not the `div#wrapper`.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You haven't posted the full html. Where is `.nav`?

Comment: @tw16 Right, fixing right now. **edit** Fixed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `.nav` is going to be relative to the `.page` and not the `#wrapper`. In order for `.nav` to be relative to `#wrapper`, you will need to move it out of the `.page` `div` and into `#wrapper`.

However it is at the bottom because you have set a `height:100%` on both `#wrapper` and `.page`, which means your `.nav` would appear at the bottom.

**EDIT :** I think I understand what you want. If you wrap the contents in the `.page` container a new `div` e.g. `.innerContent` and set that to `position:relative` it should achieve what you are trying to do. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rerqm/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page" id="first">
    <div class="innerContent">
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        <div class="nav bottom"><a href="#second">Second</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.innerContent {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: The main issue is that I want to keep everything on the same page.

Comment: One more question, why should I add extra div - which solves my issue - when .page div already has `position:relative`? Please explain if possible ;-)